# Cypress: .each loop to find element that has value

Tags: cypress

There ought to be a better way of doing this, but I can't find it.
There are a number of elements with the same selector on the page. Only the value property differs. Controls are created dynamically, so I can't pin them down any more precisely.

I am searching for an element with a specific value, using Cypress . HTML looks like this:

```
<input type="button" value="Save" data-cy-component="button-button" class="btn form-control btn-info">
```

When I find it I want to click it & jump out of the loop.

This is what I have:

```
 const buttonButton = '[data-cy-component=button-button]';
 cy.get(buttonButton).each(($el, index, $list) => {
  cy.log(`index: ` + index);
  if (index === 5) {
    cy.wrap($el)
      .should('have.value', 'Save')
      // Click Save button.
      .click();
  }
});
```

This method works, but seems vulnerable. If my Save button is no longer the 5th (or 6th) element, the test will fail. Is there a way I can test it with an IF rather than a SHOULD?

Comment: Can you provide us a snippet of HTML. You can select a element by its value using Cypress..

Comment: I know that @Maccurt. That was not the question.

Comment: I misunderstood something..

Comment: I guess you could use `cy.contains(button, 'Save').click()`. This should pick out the Save button regardless of position, and will fail if there is no Save button.

Answer (score 2):

I might not understand what you are doing, please correct me in comments if I have this wrong. What I believe you are trying to do is find a element by it's value. I wrote this and it worked. Please correct me If what you are trying to do is different..

```
<input type="button" value="Save" data-cy-component="button-button" class="btn form-control btn-info">


cy.get('[value="Save"]').should('exist');
cy.get('[value="Save"]').click();
cy.get('input[value="Save"]').should('exist');
cy.get('input[value="Save"]').click();
```

This also worked

```
cy.get('[data-cy-component=button-button][value=Save]').should('exist');
cy.get('[data-cy-component=button-button][value=Save]').click();
```

**Per your comment below you said there were 2 on the screen**

I created this HTML to test it. Notice one is hidden. I WOULD NEED TO KNOW WHAT IS MAKING YOURS HIDDEN or not visible. Also are they in different divs that perhaps have unique ids?

```
<input type="button" value="Save" data-cy-component="button-button" class="btn form-control btn-info">
<input style="visibility:hidden" type="button" value="Save" data-cy-component="button-button" class="btn form-control btn-info">


cy.get('[value="Save"][style!="visibility:hidden"]').should('length', 1);
cy.get('[value="Save"][style!="visibility:hidden"]').click();
```

Comment: Your method gives this error: CypressError: Timed out retrying: Expected to find content: 'Save' within the element: [ <input.btn.form-control.btn-info>, 1 more... ] but never did.

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstood what you are trying to do. Let me look at your question again. I would need to see your HTML to get a better understanding. My thought was you were trying to find a button that is titled "Save" and click it. I will get back to you..

Comment: cy.get('[data-cy-component=button-button][value=Save]').click()??

Comment: I changed my answer!

Comment: @Maccurt. Thanks for your help. I tried this approach: cy.get('[value="Save"]').should('exist');
cy.get('[value="Save"]').click(); I get this error: CypressError: cy.click() can only be called on a single element. Your subject contained 2 elements. Pass { multiple: true } if you want to serially click each element.

Comment: I tried it on my end with only one button. Do you have 2 buttons on your site with the value save?  That is all I could think...

Comment: My only thought is you have 2 buttons on your site with the value save. If you try this cy.get('[value="Save"]').should('length', 1); and it fails, it might shed some light on it. It is checking that there is only 1 on the page

Comment: Yes, there is definitely more than 1 of them. Only one is visible on screen however.

Comment: What is making the other input hidden or invisible. We should be able to create a selector that will exclude it. Is it style="visibility:hidden" or some other mechanism. If you can paste the html of the other button in your question, we can figure it out..